# MATE menu search - press enter behaviour

Tags: linux-mint, mate

The search feature in recent-ish versions of MATE is great, like Windows 7. Execpt that pressing Enter doesn't execute the first search result, it starts a dedicated search application. This is stupid and negates the main advantage of the feature in the first place - quick access to common things.

Anyone know of a fix? It's hard to Google and I'm having no luck finding anything relevant.

Comment: duplicate question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257783/mate-menu-linux-mint-17-searches-files-when-pressing-enter-can-this-be-chang

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is about the mintmenu. This drives me crazy as well. I created a fork of mintmenu on github that hacks in this behavior.

A few caveats: I've only tested this on Mint 17. The "install" script will overwrite the mintmenu files which have been installed by your package manager.

Installation instructions:

```
cd somewhere/src
git clone https://github.com/blc56/mintmenu.git
cd mintmenu
git checkout blc_enter
./install
```

Now log out and log back into MATE.